# Hitting governor limit while retrieving custom labels

Tags: metadata-api, customsetting, tooling-api

In the current functionality, we retrieve custom labels from the source organization. The labels are retrieved from salesforce into another Salesforce organization. However, when retrieving the labels we hit the 3 MB Web service governor limit. For the other metadata types, we first get the list of all the objects/components, and we break up those components into smaller chunks so that we can get the entire payload which is less than 3 MB.

However, with custom labels, when we just try to get the list of all the custom labels, we hit the exception. So, we have no way of retrieving the names of the custom labels or the complete definition of the custom labels.

We have tried with the metadata API as well as the tooling API.

What are you thoughts on this? How can we retrieve custom labels or custom fields from another organization without hitting this limit.

The maximum number of custom labels in an organization can be 5000. If we assume that the size of each custom level is 200 bytes, then the total size of all the custom tables is 1 MB. However, we hit still the 3 MB exception limit since the encryption/tokenization takes the rest of the space. What can we do to maximize payload size?

Please advise.

Comment: Can we achieve this via REST based metadata API calls?

Comment: Do you know what exact labels you need when creating a Web Service call?

Comment: @GrayB We neither need to get all the custom labels or labels updated in the last XX days.

Answer (score 5):

You will need to write your own custom API to return labels in batches/chunks.

It should accept Offset parameter. When offset is not passed it should return first 1000 labels. When its is 1 your API should return labels from 1001 to 2000. In your client ORG keep track of offsets and just keep passing next offset till you reach to end.

This way you should not hit 3 MB Web service governor limit.

Here is working code for your reference. I have used [this](https://github.com/BhawaniSharma/apex-mdapi) library. You just need to add logic for returning next chunks as described above.

```
    @RestResource(urlMapping='/ListLabels/*')
    global with sharing class RESTLabelController {

    @HttpGet   
      global static List<String> getLabels() {     
        List<String> lables = new List<String>();

        MetadataService.MetadataPort service = new MetadataService.MetadataPort();
        service.SessionHeader = new MetadataService.SessionHeader_element();
        service.SessionHeader.sessionId = UserInfo.getSessionId();

        List<MetadataService.ListMetadataQuery> queries = new List<MetadataService.ListMetadataQuery>();        
        MetadataService.ListMetadataQuery queryWorkflow = new MetadataService.ListMetadataQuery();
        queryWorkflow.type_x = 'CustomLabel';
        queries.add(queryWorkflow);     

        MetadataService.FileProperties[] fileProperties = service.listMetadata(queries, 25);

        for(MetadataService.FileProperties fileProperty : fileProperties){
            System.debug(fileProperty.fullName);
            lables.add(String.valueOf(fileProperty.fullName));
            If(lables.size() > 1000)
                 break;

        }
     return lables;
  }
}
```

In workbench rest explorer enter following URL and you should see the result.

> /services/apexrest/ListLabels

Comment: Are you referring to the SOAP API or REST API? Also, I cannot find the offset parameter.

Comment: I am talking about creating new custom API. SOAP or Rest is your choice. https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Creating_REST_APIs_using_Apex_REST http://www.dhruvsoft.com/blog/creating-custom-apex-soap-based-on-web-services-in-salesforce-com-and-accessing-from-java-application/

Comment: I am not really satisfied with the answer. I am not clear when you "write your custom API". well, we need to pull the data using metadata API. What are the other options? We are calling the metadata api from the apex code.

Comment: @AtulRajguru9 Are you sure the solution is feasible without using a middle ware? OP is asking for solution within Salesforce. Is webservice can handle an another call out (metadat api) which has response greater than 6MB of size?

Comment: @KevinBellati,  do you know how to create your own Custom API? if not please go through links provided. Standard API will have its own limitation and it does not provide ability of returning labels in clunks.  So what i am suggesting is to write your own API so that you can return data in clunks.

Comment: @Ashwani, If you read carefully you will realized that Kevin did not perpendicularly ask for solution within the salesforce. As standard API can not support this and it also cant support dividing payload the only option is to write your Apex code and expose that using API so that it can be called from outside world.

Comment: Also, I am not sure what do you mean by 'solution is feasible without using a middle ware' but i can guaranty that above mentioned solution will work.

Comment: @Ashwani if you have better solution then please post here.

Comment: @AtulRajguru9 will it require Java/C#/other environment to work? Also, OP has written ** The labels are retrieved from salesforce into another Salesforce organization**. I am not sure Wrapping up the metadata API with a custom web-service written in Salesforce would work if called from Salesfroce. Just a thought.

Comment: @Ashwani, It will not need any middle agent(Java/C#/other environment). I am telling so confidently that it will work because i have done something like this before. Also one point is we do not need meta data API for this we are just pulling labels in apex.

Comment: @AtulRajguru9 All custom labels form a Salesforce organisation can be retrieved my Metadata API only. Can we retrieve custom labels except "Metadata API". Custom Labels extends Metadata. If yes then I believe your solution is feasible.

Comment: ok, I i have added full functional code that returns first 1000 labels. it must resolve Kevin's problem.

Comment: @AtulRajguru9 Thank you. I appreciate your help. +1